# Problem with caret return character added to string taken from Adobe Flash input text field

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have encountered strange problem. I have created simple Flash text field control and I wanted to compare its content with some other string. This comparison in triggered when user is pressing the button.

In Action Script 2.0 code I noticed that a caret return character (\r) was added at the end of the string coming from the input text field.

It is easy to overcome the problem obviously, however I would like to understand what is going on. I use Flash CS4 with AS 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the multiline property of your textfield to false, it should fix your issue